# Configure Self-Signed certificate in azure virtual machine

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, self-signed, azure-keyvault

I have a asp.net webapplication which is ssl enabled. I would like to host this in one of the Azure VM. On my local iis , i can create a self-signed certificate. But dont know how to achieve the same on IIS in an azure VM

Can anyone help how to create self-signed certificate and configure the iis in azure VM to use this self-signed cert?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone help how to create self-signed certificate and configure
>   the iis in azure VM to use this self-signed cert?

According to your description, you could check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server).

You could create a self-signed certificate and store it into Azure Key Vault. Using following script.

```
$policy = New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy `
    -SubjectName "CN=www.contoso.com" `
    -SecretContentType "application/x-pkcs12" `
    -IssuerName Self `
    -ValidityInMonths 12

Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate `
    -VaultName $keyvaultName `
    -Name "mycert" `
    -CertificatePolicy $policy
```

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me.